# Send a solution as a single archive file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, archive, solution

It's my first time sending a solution, so I have no experience with it.
The requirement is to send a solution as a single archive file containing only source code files.

I will quote for precision:
"Send a fully buildable single solution and source code files only, excluding all binaries".

What should I do?

Comment: You should send a fully buildable single solution and source code files only, excluding all binaries, just as they requested.

Comment: how do I send only a single solution and source code files? @KenWhite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps -

1. From build menu select "Clean Solution". This will empty the `bin` folders
2. Delete all `obj` folders in all project folders. If you wish you can also remove `bin` folders, not mandatory though, as they should already be empty after step 1.
3. Delete `packages` folder from your solution directory, to remove downloaded nuget packages.

Now you should have a source only solution folder.
Now archive the full solution folder and you are good to go.

Comment: Yes, zip is one way of archiving.